Norm of a polynomial $\mathrm{Norm}_{E/K}f(x)$ where $E/K$ a field extension
This is a follow-up question to this question. Here also I am giving the lemma statement:
If $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial in $K[x]$ with no repeated factors of degree greater than $1$, then $L$ is a finite algebraic extension of $K$, and that $g(x)$ is monic, irreducible, polynomial in $L[x]$ of degree $\geq 1$, which divides $f(x)$. Put $h(x) = \textrm{Norm}_{L/K} g(x)$. Then

$\gcd(f(x),h(x))$ is an irreducible factor of degree $\geq 1$ of $f(x)$ in $K[x]$ in $K[x]$;

If the field extension $L/K$ is generated by the coefficients of $g(x)$, then $h(x)$ is already an irreducible factor of $f(x)$ in $K[X]$.


Now, I am not sure about the definition of norm $h(x) = \textrm{Norm}_{L/K} g(x)$. From this post, one can learn the definition for the norm of a polynomial, where $L/K$ is a Galois extension.  It says that $\textrm{Norm}_{L/K} g(x) = \displaystyle \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(g(x))$, where $\sigma(\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{n}a_ix^i) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\sigma(a_i)x^i$.
But my question is:  In the Lemma, it was not said that $L/K$ is a Galois extension, but they are using the concept of norm. So is there a general definition for the norm of a polynomial?
I also found a pdf, in that pdf if we look into Theorem 2.11, it is kind of saying this lemma, but not exactly this. In that pdf, a polynomial is defined that is the product of all different values of $\sigma(\pi(x))$, where $\sigma$ runs over $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$, which looks the same as the definition of norm.
But I am not sure what will be the definition of the norm for this lemma which I am trying to prove.

The only natural definition (to me at least) that extends this notion of norm of a polynomial would be to define it as the product of $\sigma(g(x))$ over embeddings $\sigma$ of $L$ into $\overline{K}$ that fix $K$ pointwise.

When $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields, we can
define the norm map ${\rm N}_{L/K} : L \to K$ without needing $L/K$ to be Galois, as follows. To each $\alpha \in L$, the multiplication-by-$\alpha$ map $m_\alpha : L \to L$ where $\beta \mapsto \alpha\beta$ is $K$-linear and thus using a $K$-basis of $L$ lets us describe $m_\alpha$ by a square matrix $[m_\alpha]$ with entries in $K$.  Set the norm of $\alpha$ to be the determinant of this matrix:
$$
{\rm N}_{L/K}(\alpha) = \det([m_\alpha]).
$$
This number is independent of the basis used. Some worked examples with this definition are here. And the fact that this definition agrees with the one you gave in case $L/K$ is Galois is Theorem 5.1 here.
The way I defined the norm map above as a determinant does not require $L$ and $K$ to be fields: they can be any commutative rings $B$ and $A$ where $A \subset B$ as long as $B$ is a free $A$-module: $B$ should have an $A$-basis. Then define ${\rm N}_{B/A} : B \to A$ by
$$
{\rm N}_{B/A}(b) = \det([m_b])
$$
for $b \in B$, where $[m_b]$ is the matrix representation of the multiplication-by-$b$ map $m_b : B \to B$ using any $A$-basis of $B$.
A particular case of this is $A = K[x]$ and $B = L[x]$. We can do this since a $K$-basis of $L$ is also a $K[x]$-basis of $L[x]$.  For example, let $K = \mathbf Q$ and $L = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$. Then $L = K + K\sqrt{2}$ and $L[x] = K[x] + K[x]\sqrt{2}$.
Let's compute
$N_{L[x]/K[x]}((4+\sqrt{2})+(1+3\sqrt{2})x)$.
Using the basis $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$,
$$
(4+\sqrt{2})+(1+3\sqrt{2})x = (4+x)+(1+3x)\sqrt{2} 
$$
so
$$
N_{L[x]/K[x]}((4+\sqrt{2})+(1+3\sqrt{2})x) = 
 N_{L[x]/K[x]}((4+x)+(1+3x)\sqrt{2}) = 
\det\begin{pmatrix}4+x&2+6x\\1+3x&4+x\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is $(4+x)^2-2(1+3x)^2$.
A $K$-basis of $L$ is not only a $K[x]$-basis of $L[x]$ but also a $K(x)$-basis of $L(x)$, with $K(x)$ and $L(x)$ being fields, so
${\rm N}_{L[x]/K[x]}(f) = {\rm N}_{L(x)/K(x)}(f)$ when $f \in L[x]$ and the norm on the right side is the concept of field norm that I discussed at the start of this answer.
What you write as ${\rm Norm}_{L/K}(g)$ means ${\rm N}_{L[x]/K[x]}(g)$ or equivalently ${\rm N}_{L(x)/K(x)}(g)$.

Thanks for the answer. So we can generalise the definition of norm.
